# update function on ajaxObject

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, web-scraping

When a button is clicked on the webpage a table of data is displayed. I want to scrape that data but I can't find where it comes from in the website source code.

This is the tag for the button:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="divChangeStateOn('load-raw-0062294377Amazon.com'); getRaw('0062294377', 'Amazon.com', 'lr-0062294377Amazon.com',this);"style="margin-bottom: 4px; width: 120px; text-align: left;" name="load-raw"><img src='images/workstation.png'/> raw data</button>
```

I believe that the getRaw function is where the data comes from (I'm not positive about this) so I looked at the javascript code for the getRaw function

```
function getRaw(asin, store, res, caller)
{ document.getElementById(res).innerHTML = '<p align="center" valign="top"><img align="center" src="phpmy_loading.gif"></p>';
    var poststr = "raw=" + encodeURI(asin) +
                "&site=" + encodeURI(store);

   var updateResults = new ajaxObject(res, 'extra.php', caller);
   updateResults.update(poststr);
}
```

I have been having a hard time finding any documentation about ajaxObject and can't find any information about the update function. What is ajaxObject.update doing and is it possible for me to access the data that appears when the button is clicked?

```
function divChangeStateOn(divID)
{ var divElem = document.getElementById(divID);
divElem.style.display = 'block';
}
```

EDIT: The link to the source code view-source:http://www.ranktracer.com/account_workstation.php  it might be password protected but I was just using the demo version

EDIT 2: 
I am basically trying to write a script that replicates the Ajax http request. This where I am at, it doesn't work and I am especially concerned about where data = uri

```
x = time.time()
print x
timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(x/1000.0)
print timestamp

uri = "raw=0062294377&site=Amazon.com&timestamp="+str(timestamp);
url = "lr-0062294377Amazon.com"

length = str(len(uri))
headers = {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
       "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       "Content-length": length,
       "Connection" : "close"}
s = Session()
r = s.post(url= url, data= uri, headers= headers)
```

Comment: Please post the entire code. ajaxObject  seems to be part of a custom code.

Answer (score 0):

The entire code for ajaxObject is present in the link you provided. Please let us know what help you are expecting here?

```
function ajaxObject(layer, url, caller) {
    if (caller) {
        disableButton(caller, 'disable');
    }
    var that = this;
    var updating = false;
    this.callback = function() {}


    var LayerID = document.getElementById(layer);

    this.update = function(passData) {
        if (updating == true) {
            return false;
        }
        updating = true;
        var AJAX = null;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            AJAX = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            AJAX = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        if (AJAX == null) {
            alert("Your browser doesn't support AJAX.");
            return false
        } else {

            AJAX.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (AJAX.readyState == 4 || AJAX.readyState == "complete") {
                    if (caller) {
                        disableButton(caller, 'enable');
                    }
                    LayerID.innerHTML = AJAX.responseText;
                    delete AJAX;
                    updating = false;
                    that.callback();

                }
            }
            var timestamp = new Date();
            var uri = passData + '&timestamp=' + (timestamp * 1);
            AJAX.open("POST", url, true);
            AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-length", uri.length);
            AJAX.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            AJAX.send(uri);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess I am trying to figure out how to replicate the ajax http request in python to call the same data that the webpage calls when you click the raw data button.